# Parent constructor taking Parent Object as a parameter

Tags: java, class, object

I  have  this  code:

```
public class Parent 
{
    int num;
    Parent p;

    Parent()
    {

    }

    Parent(Parent s)
    {
        p=s;
    }

    void Print()
    {
        System.out.println(p.num);
    }

}
```

and:

```
public class Child 
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Parent p1=new Parent();
        Parent p2=new Parent(p1);
        Parent p3=new Parent(p2);
        p2.num=5;//line 1
        p2.Print();//Line 2     
    }
}
```

The  O/p  is  0.  This  is  true  when  I replace  the  Line  1  and  2  with  `p3.num=5` and `p3.Print()`  respectively.  But  when  I  replace  it  with  `p1.num=5` and  `p1.Print()`,  I get a  Runtime  error (NullPointerException).  Can  anyone  explain  this  behavior?

Comment: Because your Default constructor isn't doing anything useful for `Parent p1 = new Parent();`. At least initialise your `int num` to 0 or something inside your Parent() default constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a *very* strange class. The `Print` method of an instance prints the `num` associated with the `p` passed into the constructor. You have two constructors, one of which doesn't ever set `p`, which means `p` will be `null` if you use that constructor; your other constructor remembers the `Parent` you give it by assigning it to `p`.

So:

- Calling `p1.Print()` will fail because `p1`'s `p` is `null`, so trying to use `p.num` throws an NPE.
- Calling `p2.Print()` will show **`p1`**'s `num`, which is `0` because you never set it to anything and the default value for data members is the "all zeroes" value, so `0` for an `int`.
- Calling `p3.Print()` will show **`p2`**'s `num`, which (in your original code) will be `5`, because that's what you set it to before calling `p3.Print()`.

The reason I say it's a very strange class is that instances have a `num` data member, but `Print` doesn't print *their* `num`, it prints the `num` of the `Parent` passed in (if any).

Comment: Thanks,  very  much.  @T.J.Crowder.  It  was  very  very  useful.  My  questions  were  the  same.  I  could  understand  that  p.print()  throwing  NullPointerException.  But  couldn't  trace  why  num  is  0  and  where  will  value  of  num=5  will  go?  This  answer  of  yours solved  my  query.

Answer (score 2):

`p1` is instantiated with the parameter-less constructor, which doesn't initialize the `p` member. Therefore, calling `Print` on that instance causes `NullPointerException` when you try to access the `num` member for a null reference - `p.num`.

BTW, the `Child` class is completely useless in this example. It doesn't extend `Parent` class, and you are not instantiating it anyway. The same code would have behaved the same if you moved the `main` method to the `Parent` class.